# In which element should I enclose an <article />'s comments?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

I'm working on a blog that implements Disqus comments and I'm making an effort to make as much use of HTML5 semantic markups as possible.

Here's an example `<article />` (itself within a `<section />`), fairly simple:

```html
  <article class="post">
    <header>
      <h2>Title</h2>
      <p class="posted-on">Posted on <time datetime="2012-07-28T13:00:24+01:00">July 28th 2012</time>.</p>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <!-- blog comments -->
  </article>
```

With the above structure, I'm unsure semantically where to integrate the article's comments.

- A [`<footer />`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-footer-element.html#the-footer-element) is clearly not appropriate ("The footer element is not sectioning content; it doesn't introduce a new section.")
- Disqus uses async JavaScript to create an `<iframe />` to contain the comment widget, so a `<p />` doesn't seem appropriate, either.

Am I over-thinking the semantic markup thing: is it best to just stick it into a `<div />` and not worry about it?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

There is an [example in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-article-element) for a blog post with comments. Which makes sense, in my opinion.

Your example could look like:

```html
  <article class="post">
    <header>
      <h1>Title</h1>
      <p class="posted-on">Posted on <time datetime="2012-07-28T13:00:24+01:00">July 28th 2012</time>.</p>
    </header>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

    <section>
      <h1>Comments</h1>

      <article><!-- comment 1--></article>
      <article><!-- comment 2--></article>
      <article><!-- comment 3--></article>

    <section>

  </article>
```

---

Side note: I think your "`posted-on`" would better fit into a [`footer`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-footer-element) instead of a [`header`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-header-element). So your `header` could be omitted because it would only contain the heading. So your example could look like:

```html
  <article class="post">

    <h1>Title</h1>

    <footer class="posted-on">Posted on <time datetime="2012-07-28T13:00:24+01:00">July 28th 2012</time>.</footer>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

    <section>
      <h1>Comments</h1>

      <article><!-- comment 1--></article>
      <article><!-- comment 2--></article>
      <article><!-- comment 3--></article>

    <section>

  </article>
```

Comment: Thanks unor. I wonder why the comments title is enclosed with an `<h1 />` while the article's title is enclosed within an `<h2 />`; that seems wrong to me (they could very well *both* be `<h1 />`s though). Also, I had considered putting the "posted on" data within a `<footer />` (but at the top of the article, as you suggest) but even the spec on `<article />` you link puts it in the `<header />`, while the specs suggest that footer might well be more appropriate. Is there a semantic advantage to putting it in a `<footer />`?

Comment: @msanford: Regarding the headings: it doesn't matter which level you choose, the first heading (no matter the level) will be the heading of the section. Typically, you'd always use `h1`, or you'd use the level corresponding to the overall outline. So yes, it's not very good style to mix this; I updated the code in my answer.

Comment: @msanford: Regarding `footer` vs `header`: I think we should use the elements according to the *normative* definition in the specification, not the *informative* examples. Because the *normative* information is what all the other entities (screenreaders, search engines, …) will (or better: should) use to program their software.  However, this very case (the difference between `footer` and `header`) is not perfectly clear. So I wouldn't say it's an *error* to use `header` for publication date.

Answer (score 9):

You could stick it in its own `<section>` (rather than a `<div>`) within your containing `<section>`, as a sibling of your `<article>`. But if you're using Disqus, I guess whichever element you use doesn't matter. I don't think it belongs within the article content though. Maybe an `<aside>` instead?

Just keep in mind that when it comes to semantics, there aren't any hard and fast rules. As long as your document is structured and outlined in a meaningful way, that's what matters.

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I had considered putting it in its own `<section />`, but I hadn't considered putting it outside the `<article />` as its sibling. That might be a perfect solution! I don't however think that `<aside />` would be appropriate, because ("The aside element represents a section of a page that consists of content that is *tangentially related* to the content around the aside element, and which could be considered separate from that content." (http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/the-aside-element.html#the-aside-element).

Answer (score 0):

`My Preference 1:`

```
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      "tweet" or "article" or "blog post" or "forum post" content goes here...
      <section class="comments">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <ol>
          <li>
            <div class="comment">
              comment goes here...  
            </div>
          </li>
          <li>    
            <div class="comment">
              comment goes here...
            </div>
          </li>
          ....... more comments
        </ol>
      </section>
    </article>      
  </main>
</body>
```

In my above implementation, comments are nested within an `article` element because they are directly related to the content of the tweet, article, blog post, or forum post. However, I further group them within a `section` element for clear organization and visual separation. Now, wrapping each comment in an `article` element would mean each comment is distributable independently and still self-contained, which is not accurate as each comment is related to the topic of the tweet, article, blog post, or forum post. So, I wrapped each comment within the `div` element.

So, the above given HTML5 structure aligns the best according to the semantic meaning.

`My Preference 2:`

If you think the comments are not part of the tweet, article, blog post, or forum post, then the following HTML5 structure is also my other preference:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      "tweet" or "article" or "blog post" or "forum post" content goes here... 
    </article>
    <section class="comments">
      <h1>Comments</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>
          <div class="comment">
            comment goes here...  
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>    
          <div class="comment">
            comment goes here...
          </div>
        </li>
        ....... more comments
      </ol> 
    </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

This HTML5 structure also aligns well with semantic meaning.

`My Preference 3:`

If you think the tweet, article, blog post, or forum post is the only main content of the particular webpage, then consider the following HTML5 structure:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <article>
      "tweet" or "article" or "blog post" or "forum post" content goes here... 
    </article>
  </main>  
  <section class="comments">
    <h1>Comments</h1>
    <ol>
      <li>
        <div class="comment">
          comment goes here...  
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>    
        <div class="comment">
          comment goes here...
        </div>
      </li>
      ....... more comments
    </ol> 
  </section>
</body>
```

I hope this helps.